# ASP.NET MVC - How to Validate Dropdownlist to be compulsory from Controller or View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please how do I validate my Dropdownlist to be compulsory from Controller or View. I dont want to do it from Model.

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.OPTION_ID, "Parent", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @{
        List<SelectListItem> dropdownlist3 = new List<SelectListItem>();
        dropdownlist3.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Please Select Parent--", Value = "-1" });

        foreach (var item in Model.list)
        {

            dropdownlist3.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.OPTION_VALUE, Value = item.OPTION_ID.ToString() });
        }

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.item.PARENT_ID, dropdownlist3, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdown", })
        @Html.HiddenFor(n => n.item.PARENT_ID1, new { @id = "parentid1" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(n => n.item.PARENT_ID2, new { @id = "parentid2" })


    }
</div>
```

If dropdownlist is not having any value, then save will not be allowed.

I don't want to validate from Model

Comment: In the controller action check if the field has a value.  It's just an `if` statement.  Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Use a view model with `[Required]` data annotation and make use of the model validation framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use java script in view then you can use following Java script of validate.js.

```
 $("#frmId").validate({
                rules: {
                    myFieldName: {
                        required: 'true'// <-  declare the rule
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    myFieldName: {
                        required: "myFieldName is required",
                    },

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Note: This does not make the value required in the controller, which was also mentioned in the question.  This merely suggests to the UI that a value is required, but at the controller level it does not actually require a value.